# Using a custom value for text-overflow

Tags: html, css

Just found a gem of a property called text `text-overflow` , i like its value to be set to `ellipsis` and it works just fine, **[SEE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/0n5b7byc/)**,

I was reading the **[MDN doc's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)** here.

But if in the fiddle or locally , if i change the `text-overflow: '...'` , i don't see any difference in the browser, I.E. i don't see the `text-overflow` property applied at all , no effect.

Why are custom values not taking effect than ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: Because except in Firefox custom values aren't legal. Read the page you cited.

Comment: @j08691 Danm !! thanks ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the whole docs page, there is a section on browser compatibility. Currently, according to the doc, the only browser (mobile and desktop) that is compatible with string values is Firefox 9.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read better your MDN link. `<string>` value is experimental and as you can see at the table on bottom, supported only by Firefox.